# cout.setf(ios::fixed) and cout << fixed do not seem to get the same result?

Tags: c++, formatting, cout, outputstream

this is my sample main :

```
double hours = 35.45;
double rate = 15.00;
double tolerance = 0.01000;

cout.setf(ios::scientific);
cout << "Scientific notation: " << endl;
cout << "hours = " << hours << ", rate = " << rate << ", pay = "
    << hours * rate << ", tolerance = " << tolerance << endl << endl;

cout.setf( ios::fixed ); // if i replace but cout << fixed, it works
cout << setprecision( 3 );
cout << "Fixed decimal notation: " << endl;
cout << "hours = " << hours << ", rate = " << rate << ", pay = "
    << hours * rate << ", tolerance = " << tolerance << endl << endl;

system( "pause" );
```

Why are they not equal? if they are equal then what is wrong here?

Comment: Where is your [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: This is my minimal testcase : double hours = 35.45;
 cout.setf(ios::scientific);
 cout.setf( ios::fixed ); 
 cout << "hours = " << hours << endl;

Comment: .............. read the page I just linked you to. Completely. That is _not_ a minimal testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag `std::ios_base::fixed` is just one of two flags in `std::ios_base::floatfield`. The function `std::ios_base::setf()` is oblivious of the relationship between the different flags and merely sets a bit pattern. If you want to set `std::ios_base::fixed` and clear other fields from the subgroup, you'd use

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
```

When you use the manipulator `std::fixed` it is equivalent to this call.